# Organizing modules in a D project

Tags: module, coding-style, naming-conventions, d

I come from Java backgrounds and the problem of packaging is as follows then:

I can have many files under the same package, say `com.parobay.io`. I can then distribute this as a library, and the users will use it like this:

```
import com.parobay.io.Input;
import com.parobay.io.Output;
```

or

```
import com.parobay.io.*; // to import everything
```

So I can have a single "module (`com.parobay.io`) and classes defined in multiple files.

So how to I achieve the same in D? Do I have to create a directory `com\parobay\io` and there place two files called `Input.d` and `Output.d` or is there a smarter way?

In Java the rules are very strict, so it's hard to get it wrong. In D there are many possibilities. So are there any conventions, like one class per file, or file name equal to the name of class?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can choose to do it basically the same as Java, though remember these items:

- import `foo.*` doesn't work in D, but you CAN make a file called `package.d` in the directory which manually lists `public import foo.Input; public import foo.Output;` etc. which allows you to import the whole package.
- ALWAYS put a `module com.parobay.io.Input;` or whatever line at the top of any file that is imported. Don't expect it to just work based on directory structure and filename. The directory structure actually isn't strictly necessary, it is just a convention to easily find the file. The `module` line at the top with the name is the authoritative thing the compiler checks.
- D modules often have all lowercase names, but you can use uppercase ones if you like. I think it is nice to use a lowercase name like the class name, so you might call the module `io.input` and the class `Input`. The reason for this convention is sometimes filename case gets lost when transferring from system to system. But developers are pretty aware of case so in practice either way should work.
- One class per file will work fine or you can put two tightly coupled classes together in the same file (they'll have access to each other's private members if they are in the same file).

See this page for more info: http://dlang.org/module especially search for the heading "Package Module"

Comment: Thank you for your response. And what if I want to distribute this as a library, how would you approach this? What do I need to prepare for the others to use it? (e.g. in java I can send a JAR, in c++ I can send a `.a` file with headers, or a DLL)

Comment: @Parobay You'd do it like you would in C++.  Just use D interface files instead of header files.

Comment: @Adam thank you; do you recommend an article (if one exists) on publishing open source libraries? What if I wrote a small lib, and wanted to get it reviewed a bit and perhaps released (to dub?). What should I do?

Comment: This might help: http://code.dlang.org/package-format see the other projects there as examples. If you register on code.dlang.org it lets you add github repos to the list. If you want some review, post it to the announce group on http://forum.dlang.org/ and ask us there to take a look. Might not get a huge reply but you should get someone to take a look.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use two separate files for your `Input` and `Output` classes.  Instead, put both classes in a single file, `parobay/io.d` (corresponding to the module `parobay.io`).

It's definitely *not* the convention to limit yourself to just one class per file.  D modules are for grouping together code of related functionality.  When someone does `import parobay.io;`, they expect to get *all* of `parobay.io` - classes, utility functions and whatever else is relevant.  It's similar to Java's `import com.parobay.io.*;`.

If someone really wants to import specific parts of your module, they can use *selective imports:*

```
import parobay.io: Input; // Just the Input class of the parobay.io module.
import parobay.io: Output; // Just the Output class.
import parobay.io: Input, Output; // Just the Input and Output classes.
```

There are a few additional things to note about this.

- Package and module names are conventionally all-lowercase.
- It makes everyone's lives easier if the path to the file matches up exactly with its full module name.  For example, module `foo.bar.baz` should be in the file `foo/bar/baz.d`.
- In my experience, it's rare for a D module to be named after a domain name.  You can prefix your module names with `com` or `org` or `net` if you really want to, but it's not expected like it is in Java.

[Adam D. Ruppe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23912196/497934) has some great points about explicit module declarations and class member visibility.  It's also well worth reading the [module](http://dlang.org/module.html) and [style](http://dlang.org/dstyle.html) pages on [the official D website](http://dlang.org/).

Comment: I disagree with the suggestion not to prefix packages with domain names (in reverse order). It is a good practice, and not only used in Java but widely across various communities. Once D becomes more present in enterprise world this will almost be a must, because there will be so many packages and modules with same names. Having domain prefix avoids this problem entirely.

Comment: @DejanLekic I don't think it's worth worrying about name collisions.  Their risk is way overstated. C++ `#include` paths don't follow Java's domain name pattern, and that's worked out fine even though C++ is just as popular as Java and has a much less sophisticated notion of a module.  If you want to use domain names for your modules because it's what you've always done or because you need to stay consistent with an existing codebase, then that's fine.  But doing it because you're worried about future name collisions is just paranoid.

Comment: This simple convention avoids all the possible headaches completely, and that is precisely the reason why it is used in so many places. Also, it is not uncommon in C++ world either. I have actually used commercial C++ libraries with tld::domain::etc namespaces in the past and I know perfectly what I am talking about, "a posteriori".

Comment: @DejanLekic I edited my answer so that it no longer discourages the use of the domain name module convention.

Comment: @Maxpm hey, thanks for the answer. Regarding *modules are for grouping together code of related functionality.*: what if `Input` and `Output` are big classes - I don't want to end up with 2 big classes in a single file, it'll be hard to maintain. Do you suggest to create `io.input`, `io.output` modules and a `io` module publicly  importing input and output?

Comment: @Parobay Yes, that's a perfectly valid solution.

Answer (score 2):

D community has three widely accepted alternatives.

1. Write a module named `all.d` which includes all modules from your package. (Literally '*' --> 'all'). After that you simply do `import com.paroboy.io.all;`
2. I see more and more that D developers use `_` for this. So they write a module called `_.d` for this purpose. Similarly to #1, you do `import com.paroboy.io._;`
3. Relatively new addition to the D programming language is the `package.d` module, which can be used to import the package. More about this at the following DIP: http://wiki.dlang.org/DIP37 . If I remember well, DMD supports it since v2.064 . (Documentation: http://dlang.org/module#PackageModule)

I myself use the #1 approach because it is obvious what is going on. While #2 and #3 may be confusing to people reading D source file, especially the third one. A valid question someone may ask: *"What the heck am I importing, package?? But `import` is only for modules!??"*

Allthough nothing stops you from having separate module per-class, I would not recommend it. D is truly modular language, so take advantage of that. Group *all* your types in a single D module. That is my advice, and that is the "D way".

**NOTE:**
There is a (big) semantic difference between Java "module" and a D module, as you have probably already noticed. I am primarily a Java programmer, so I know how confusing this may be to Java programmers who are playing with D. Java classes in the same package quite often take advantage of the package-level access. However, classes within the same module behave like "friends" in C++.

Speaking about [Java modules](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/), they were supposed to come with Java 8 (true modules!), but were posponed and will hopefully be included in Java 9.

**UPDATE:** We reached conclusion, after a chat on [FreeNode (IRC)](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=#d&uio=d4) with some members of the [D-Programming-Language](https://github.com/D-Programming-Language), that it is indeed safe now to use the `package` attribute. It behaves as the specification says.

Comment: "It is yet to be determined what D's `package` protection attribute does..." What makes you say that?  According to [this](http://dlang.org/attribute.html#ProtectionAttribute), it's very well-defined.  "Package extends private so that package members can be accessed from code in other modules that are in the same package. This applies to the innermost package only, if a module is in nested packages."

Comment: As far as I know, package attribute does not work. I remember there were threads on the D newsgroups about issues with it. Finally, I have never seen a D project where package attribute is used, have you? :)

Comment: @DejanLekic thank you. I like the `package.d` approach since it looks like designed for this purpose. I've just read some Facebook and vibe.d D code and they use similar approach. On the other hand, they have D modules that are several KLOC in size (to keep all classes/structs/.. in a single module?), which worries me. Can you somehow split interfaces from implementation (like headers in c++?)

Comment: @Parobay The DMD compiler supports creating [D interface files](http://dlang.org/dmd-linux.html#interface_files) from source files.  D interface files are comparable to C++ headers.